# How to make ItemTempleField to ReadOnly Field in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box in a gridview that i would like to make it on ReadOnly but the text-box is disabled now and i want to change to ReadOnly so users can scroll up and down to see all the contents of the field. I basically want to restrict the field so users cannot type anything but at the sametime they should be able to scroll up and down.  Here is what i have now:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    ((TextBox)gvr.FindControl("myTextBox")).Enabled = false;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `readonly` attribute to the control instead of disabling it:

```
((TextBox)gvr.FindControl("myTextBox")).Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

If you set `.Enabled = false;` or `.ReadOnly = true;` no values will be posted back (I'm not assuming you need them but just in case you do).

Answer (score 0):

You should make the textbox readonly...
you could also do so if the boundfield is converted to a template field..

```
<EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" Height="74px" ReadOnly="True" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("address") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="182px"></asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

The value for ReadOnly should be True and not ReadOnly ok..
Even if you do it at runtime using findcontrol then use True for ReadOnly.